# Using union and order by clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I want to use order by with union in mysql query.
I am fetching different types of record based on different criteria from a table based on distance for a search on my site.
The first select query returns data related to the exact place search .
The 2nd select query returns data related to distance within 5 kms from the place searched.
The 3rd select query returns data related to distance within 5-15 kms from the place searched.

Then i m using union to merge all results and show on a page with paging. Under appropriate heading as **'Exact search results'**, **'Results within 5 kms'** etc

Now i want to sort results based on id or add_date. But when i add order by clause at the end of my query ( query1 union query 2 union query 3 order by add_date). It sorts all results. But what i want is it should sort under each heading.

Comment: What type(s) is/are the field(s) you want to sort by in each table?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You can do this by adding a pseudo-column named rank to each select, that you can sort by first, before sorting by your other criteria, e.g.:

```
select *
from (
    select 1 as Rank, id, add_date from Table 
    union all
    select 2 as Rank, id, add_date from Table where distance < 5
    union all
    select 3 as Rank, id, add_date from Table where distance between 5 and 15
) a
order by rank, id, add_date desc
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, i am exactly using this way. But what i want is that i want to sort select query result based on add_date in descending order.

Comment: You can use the `desc` keyword for this. I updated the query above.

Comment: I just made a quick change in codes, and the results was awesome. You made my day. Thanks

Comment: Why there is `a` and the end?

Comment: MySQL requires that derived tables have an alias.

Comment: @RedFilter, I don't quite get it. What's the whole point of "select all as a derived table" when we **can simply** select all 3 tables then do an `order by`? ([*"to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one"*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html))  . Compare your code with http://i.stack.imgur.com/LpTMU.png

Comment: @Pacerier If that syntax works with MySQL, go for it! My syntax is a little more cross-platform, I don't generally work with MySQL. I actually prefer it, though, as it works in more generalized cases, e.g., consider when you only want the first ten matches from from the last UNION query - I think you would have to fall back to my syntax anyway.

Comment: @RedFilter, Yes that syntax works even in MySQL 4.1.

Comment: @Pacerier, also consider that the value in this way allows that top "select *" to instead be "select id, add_date" and strip "rank" out of the results if you didn't want to see them.

Comment: @DevNull, Yep that's one valid use case.

Comment: The subquery is not necessary in MySQL -- at least not in any recent version.

Comment: Reminder, excerpt from the documentation:
_The UNION can have global ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses, which affect the whole resultset. If the columns retrieved by individual SELECT statements have an alias (AS), the ORDER BY must use that alias, not the real column names._

Answer (score 51):

You can use subqueries to do this:

```
select * from (select values1 from table1 order by orderby1) as a
union all
select * from (select values2 from table2 order by orderby2) as b
```

Comment: Tnx, Good one to separate orders. Also we can have a different arrangement if the order clause was common but we want the results separated(instead of separating orders) :

`SELECT * FROM (
SELECT aaa AS Col, 1 AS Official FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT bbb AS Col, 0 AS Official FROM table2
) AS tbl
ORDER BY Official, Col`

Comment: This is [incorrect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html): *use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result*

Comment: You are right, the accepted answer is also the correct one. This just happened to work well when I tested it.

Comment: shmosel (and rickythefox) -- union all does not remove duplicates, and so has no reason to change the sort of your individual sorted selects.  This is why it worked for you in the past, and why it will work for you in the future.  The order being messed up in the final result is due to UNION (DISTINCT) needing some kind of sort to combine rows efficiently. Or more specifically, sorts because it combines rows efficiently.  So you can depend on union all to preserve your subqueries.

Comment: This was working great for older MySQL versions, now this approach will **NOT** work. Because SQL standard do not guarantee to preserve order of subquery.

Answer (score 42):

```
(select add_date,col2 from table_name) 
  union 
(select add_date,col2 from table_name) 
  union 
(select add_date,col2 from table_name) 

order by add_date
```

Comment: This worked, but oddly I needed to change one thing: I needed to give a shared alias to the field that was ordering by.  Worked besides that, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget, union all is a way to add records to a record set without sorting or merging (as opposed to union).

So for example:

```
select * from (
    select col1, col2
    from table a
    <....>
    order by col3
    limit by 200
) a
union all
select * from (
    select cola, colb
    from table b
    <....>
    order by colb
    limit by 300
) b
```

It keeps the individual queries clearer and allows you to sort by different parameters in each query.  However by using the selected answer's way it might become clearer depending on complexity and how related the data is because you are conceptualizing the sort.  It also allows you to return the artificial column to the querying program so it has a context it can sort by or organize.

But this way has the advantage of being fast, not introducing extra variables, and making it easy to separate out each query including the sort.  The ability to add a limit is simply an extra bonus.

And of course feel free to turn the union all into a union and add a sort for the whole query.  Or add an artificial id, in which case this way makes it easy to sort by different parameters in each query, but it otherwise is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: You do not need the `select * from ` at the start, see the other answer of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042973/mitali). Works for me. Your answer is also right, and it shows that you can use `order by` and `limit` in a union, you only need to put each block in brackets (or in a select query, as in your example). Else, you would get [error #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763644/getting-error-1221-incorrect-usage-of-union-and-limit). Also explained in the answer of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4371791/tom-headifen).

Comment: You can start with "I'm right", and then follow up with ", and you can simplify the query if sorting or limiting are not required on the subquery level by removing the select *".   The OP wanted each part sorted..

Comment: Not meant with my comment. Your answer is right. OK, first point. The second is that you can even shorten it to the two sub queries just in their brackets instead of the `select * from (...) my_table_alias`-frame around each of the two. Also good in your answer (as well as in the shortened version of it): you can use `order by` and `limit` which would not work without your subquery frame or without the mere brackets. This is not against your answer, it is just a side remark.

Answer (score 11):

A union query can only have one master `ORDER BY` clause, IIRC. To get this, in each query making up the greater `UNION` query, add a field that will be the one field you sort by for the `UNION`'s `ORDER BY`.

For instance, you might have something like

```
SELECT field1, field2, '1' AS union_sort
UNION SELECT field1, field2, '2' AS union_sort
UNION SELECT field1, field2, '3' AS union_sort
ORDER BY union_sort
```

That `union_sort` field can be anything you may want to sort by. In this example, it just happens to put results from the first table first, second table second, etc.

Answer (score 10):

When you use an `ORDER BY` clause inside of a sub query used in conjunction with a `UNION` mysql will optimise away the `ORDER BY` clause.

This is because by default a `UNION` returns an unordered list so therefore an `ORDER BY` would do nothing.

The optimisation is mentioned [in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) and says:

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10) UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```
>
> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies
>   nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result
>   because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore,
>   the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with
>   LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows
>   to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect
>   the order of those rows in the final UNION result. If ORDER BY appears
>   without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have
>   no effect anyway.

The last sentence of this is a bit misleading because it should have an effect. This optimisation causes a problem when you are in a situation where you need to order within the subquery.

To force MySQL to not do this optimisation you can add a LIMIT clause like so:

```
(SELECT 1 AS rank, id, add_date FROM my_table WHERE distance < 5 ORDER BY add_date LIMIT 9999999999)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 AS rank, id, add_date FROM my_table WHERE distance BETWEEN 5 AND 15 ORDER BY rank LIMIT 9999999999)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 3 AS rank, id, add_date from my_table WHERE distance BETWEEN 5 and 15 ORDER BY id LIMIT 9999999999)
```

A high `LIMIT` means that you could add an `OFFSET` on the overall query if you want to do something such as pagination.

This also gives you the added benefit of being able to `ORDER BY` different columns for each union.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working on a join plus union.

```
(SELECT 
   table1.column1,
   table1.column2,
   foo1.column4
 FROM table1, table2, foo1, table5
 WHERE table5.somerecord = table1.column1
 ORDER BY table1.column1 ASC, table1.column2 DESC
)

UNION

(SELECT
    ... Another complex query as above
)

ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2 ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

i was trying **(order by after union)** for below query, but couldn't:

```
select table1.*,table2.* 
from table1 
left join table2 on table2.id=0 
   union
select table1.*,table2.* 
from table2 
left join table1 on table2.i=table1.id
order by table1.id;
```

whatever your query is,
**just add a same name alias in column, in all your select union queries**
in above example it will be:

```
select table1.id as md,table1.*,table2.* 
from table1 
left join table2 on table2.id=0 
   union
select table1.id as md,table1.*,table2.* 
from table2 
left join table1 on table2.i=table1.id
order by md;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT result.* 
FROM (
 [QUERY 1]
 UNION
 [QUERY 2]
) result
ORDER BY result.id
```

Where [QUERY 1] and [QUERY 2] are your two queries that you want to merge.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the order by to each of the queries prior to unioning like

```
(select * from table where distance=0 order by add_date) 
union 
(select * from table where distance>0 and distance<=5 order by add_date)
```

but it didn't seem to work. It didn't actually do the ordering within the rows from each select.

I think you will need to keep the order by on the outside and add the columns in the where clause to the order by, something like

```
(select * from table where distance=0) 
union 
(select * from table where distance>0 and distance<=5) 
order by distance, add_date
```

This may be a little tricky, since you want to group by ranges, but I think it should be doable.

Comment: user151841 union_sort idea below would be a nice way to handle the grouping

Comment: this is not what op wants

Answer (score 1):

Just use order by column number (don't use column name).
Every query returns some columns, so you can order by any desired column using it's number.

Answer (score 1):

We can use ORDER BY clause with UNION result, after researching for a long time, I finally came to a solution.

In MySQL if you use parenthesis then scope of query is limited to parenthesis, if you want to sort the UNION result data coming from two or more complex queries use all SELECT and UNION statement in one line and in ORDER BY clause use the name of column you want to sort.

EX: `SELECT * FROM customers UNION SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name DESC`

If you are using JOIN in SELECT queries than use only column name only not with the table variable name

EX: `SELECT c.name,c.email FROM customers as c JOIN orders as o ON c.id=o.id UNION SELECT u.name,u.email FROM users as u JOIN inventory as i ON u.id=i.id ORDER BY name DESC`

Answer (score 0):

This is because You're sorting entire result-set, You should sort, every part of union separately, or You can use ORDER BY (Something ie. subquery distance) THEN (something ie row id) clause

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution is to create a CTE

```
WITH cte as (
(SELECT * FROM table1)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT * FROM table2)
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY col1
```