# SQL query with multiple ORDER BY Field statements - or perhaps a new approach?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I'm attempting to build a query that finds companies that are within a proximity/distance from a zip code.

Right now a user enters a zip code (via web form) and a radius (1, 5, 10 miles, etc) and I'm using [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-zip-code-range-and-distance-calculation.html) PHP class to find the closest zip codes, radius, distance, etc (which is working great). Then I have a query that finds all companies which have these zip codes and lists them out.

The issue I have is that the zip codes are stored in three places in the database. They are either stored in the companies table, and/or one of two other related tables (simplified example below). And I can't figure out how to ORDER the results by the proximity regardless of where the zip code field is.

Tables:

company (table) id, name, zip

company_delivery (table) id, company_id (fk), zip

company_other_areas (table) id, company_id (fk), zip

$zip_codes is an array of zips outputted from the zip code class noted above where they are listed closest to furthest:

```
$zip_code_array = array(
    90210,
    90211,
    90212
)

//* edited - thanks @crafter
$zip_codes = implode(', ', $zip_code_array);
```

The Query I'm working with

```
$sql="
SELECT
  company.id, company.name, company.zip, company_delivery.zip, company_other_areas.zip
FROM
  company
LEFT JOIN
  company_delivery ON company.id = company_delivery.company_id
LEFT JOIN
company_other_areas ON company.id = company_other_areas.company_id
WHERE
  company.zip IN($zip_codes) OR company_delivery.zip IN($zip_codes) OR company_other_areas.zip IN($zip_codes)
GROUP BY
  company.id
ORDER BY
  FIELD(company.zip, $zip_codes),
  FIELD(company_delivery.postal_code, $zip_codes)
  FIELD(company_other_areas.postal_code, $zip_codes)
";
```

I can't seem to figure out to order the companies by zip code, in the same order they are returned from the Zip Code class. - With the above query it orders by each "FIELD" independently. Is it possible to put all the returned zips codes from the database into a merged variable that can be ordered by?

Thanks for any help or pointers on this!

Comment: You can merge the tables using UNION

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks! - This seems like a good idea, however the three zip tables all have equal priority. Or, perhaps I'm just not understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FIELD(company.zip, $zip_codes),
FIELD(company_delivery.postal_code, $zip_codes)
FIELD(company_other_areas.postal_code, $zip_codes)
```

with

```
COALESCE(
    FIELD(company.zip, $zip_codes),
    FIELD(company_delivery.postal_code, $zip_codes)
    FIELD(company_other_areas.postal_code, $zip_codes)
)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I attempted to use COALESCE as you had suggested but the results are still somewhat random. (ie, Companies with zip 90212 listed before companies with zip 90210). Is there a way to merge the three tables results into a new temp variable to ORDER by? thanks again!

Comment: All that `COALESCE` does is choosing the first non-`NULL`-value among the provided values. Is there something else, you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'd `COALESCE` the fields in the `SELECT` clause, then order by column number in the order by clause. Like this:

```
SELECT company.id, 
       company.name, 
       COALESCE(company.zip, company_delivery.zip, company_other_areas.zip) AS zip_code
  FROM company
  LEFT JOIN company_delivery ON company.id = company_delivery.company_id
  LEFT JOIN company_other_areas ON company.id = company_other_areas.company_id
 WHERE (   company.zip IN($zip_codes) 
        OR company_delivery.zip IN($zip_codes) 
        OR company_other_areas.zip IN($zip_codes)
       )
 GROUP BY company.id
 ORDER BY 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using union, a temporary table will be created which will have records from three queries and order by clause will sort the records regardless of the sequence of queries.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what the query would look like using UNION w/ related tables? MySQL is complaining that the tables don't have/match the correct number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that

```
SELECT company.name, a.company_id, a.zip FROM ( SELECT id AS company_id, zip FROM company UNION ALL SELECT company.id, zip FROM company_delivery  UNION ALL SELECT company.id, zip FROM company_other_areas ) a JOIN company ON a.company_id = company.id ORDER BY a.zip;
```