# MySQL: can't order one side of a union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...) UNION (SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...)
```

Because I want the results from the first `SELECT` to come out on top. But, the second part comes out in reverse order. I can't simply order the entire query because it will push the first `SELECT` that I need at the top to the bottom... So I want to do something like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...) UNION (SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...  ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
```

But this just doesn't work, the `ORDER BY` is completely ignored; I tested this by inserting gibberish, `ORDER BY dosaif30h` still works... One solution would be to make two separate queries, but I'd much prefer to handle it in one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using union and order by clause in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: @JaugarChang that question is looking to order the entire UNION result... not the same problem

Comment: But the accepted answer gives you enough hint.

Comment: Do you get the same result using Union All? Union eliminates duplicates; the engine has to sort the results to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM something WHERE ... UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...  ORDER BY timestamp DESC)a
```

Comment: without the a on the end I got `OperationalError: (1248, 'Every derived table must have its own alias')` and with it... `Syntax Error`

Comment: @AllTheTime Note the `a` I added at the end. That's the alias that you must have. Add that.

Comment: Your answer is super close and it got me to this... which works. Edit your answer and I will accept. `(SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...) UNION ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM something WHERE ...  ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as a )`

Comment: @AllTheTime Try doing what I did in my answer, that should work as well (that's how I do it). Actually, it's equivalent to what you have, except less characters (better readability?).

Comment: strange. Must be the version / engine I'm using (MySQLdb for python) It only works for me with the brackets and verbosity displayed in the above comment.

Comment: @AllTheTime Oh I found the mistake. The first statement shouldn't have had the parentheses. Try it now.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  There is no guarantee that the results of a `union` will be in the order of the query or that the ordering in a subquery is respected.  In most cases, the only way to guarantee the ordering of a query is to use an `order by` at the outermost level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order both of them in one order, then you need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table_1 where something
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE something
) as tt
ORDER BY something
```

Note that both tables should have same column names and count.

If you want to order only the second query then:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 where something
        UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE something ORDER BY something) as tt
```

Comment: I don't think you need the sub-query. `ORDER BY` applies to the entire union

Comment: I only want to order the second `select` before the union is made

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first table to come first, then you need to order by that explicitly:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM ((SELECT s.*, 1 as which FROM something s WHERE ...)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT s.*, 2 as which FROM something s WHERE ...)
     ) s
ORDER BY which, timestamp DESC
```

You can only trust an `order by` in the outer query -- in most circumstances -- if you want the results in a particular order.

NOTE:  You can write this without the subquery if you like:

```
SELECT s.*, 1 as which FROM something s WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT s.*, 2 as which FROM something s WHERE ...
ORDER BY which, timestamp;
```