# Union order by problems

Tags: mysql, sql, union

The code below works fine up till the point i try to order it by name.

first time working with union so little confused on how to order these tables together when the first column names are different.

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_name 'Name',
    e.emp_gen 'Gender',
    ('Employee') 'Role'
FROM employee e
ORDER BY e.emp_name ASC
        UNION ALL
SELECT 
    s.sup_name 'Name',
    s.gen 'Gender',
    ('Supervisor') 'Role'
FROM supervisor s
ORDER BY s.sup_name ASC;
```

**EDIT**

have now tried this but doesn't seem to work as well

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_name 'Name',
    e.emp_gen 'Gender',
    ('Employee') 'Role'
FROM employee e
        UNION ALL
SELECT 
    s.sup_name 'Name',
    s.gen 'Gender',
    ('Supervisor') 'Role'
FROM supervisor s
ORDER BY s.sup_name ASC;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using union and order by clause in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: You need to `ORDER` the entire result set _after_ the `UNION`, q.v. Robby Cornelissen's link.

Comment: `UNION` is almost always a bad idea IMHO. You'd be much better off making  a common person table (use "employee", one would assume that supervisors are still employees) and setting a field to define the role.

Comment: the teacher has required us to use a union so we understand how they work

Comment: @terribleprogramming u want to show supervisor names first?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

everything was working fine like i said up till the 'order by', i think because of the fact that the name columns for the two tables were different so i changed the order by statement to reference the column.

i forgot you could do this.

also i did not mean to have union 'all' this was something i was just playing around with while stuck.

sorry if i confused people with that union all

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_name 'Name',
    e.emp_gen 'Gender',
    ('Employee') 'Role'
FROM employee e
        UNION
SELECT 
    s.sup_name 'Name',
    s.gen 'Gender',
    ('Supervisor') 'Role'
FROM supervisor s
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Comment: ORDER BY 'Name' ASC is better. (Order by ordinal position is deprecated.) Why ( )s around 'Employee' and 'Supervisor'? Why UNION instead of UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to order by name itself like below.

```
SELECT EMPNAME AS COL1, DOB FROM #TABLE1
UNION
SELECT SUPNAME AS COL1, DOB FROM #TABLE2
ORDER BY COL1
```

Or

```
SELECT EMPNAME 'COL1', DOB FROM #TABLE1
UNION
SELECT SUPNAME 'COL1', DOB FROM #TABLE2
ORDER BY COL1
```