# Getting error #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make union query with this two queries using `union` between the queries but getting error #121 Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT. Please help me to make this union queries to get result both of this queries.

query1:

```
SELECT t1.TraineeID,
       t2.attnDate,
       MIN(t1.attnTime) AS inTime,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(t1.attnTime) < MAX(t1.attnTime) THEN MAX(t1.attnTime) else '' end) AS outTime,
       (CASE WHEN t5.Slot ='1' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'P' 
             WHEN t5.Slot ='2' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t5.Slot ='3' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t5.Slot ='4' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t5.Slot ='1' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'Early Out' 
             WHEN t5.Slot ='2' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN t5.Slot ='3' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN t5.Slot ='4' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'Early Out'
             ELSE 'Late-In'
       END) AS Status

FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_assigned t3, tbl_batch t5
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT attnDate FROM tbl_attn_temp) t2
WHERE t1.attndate = t2.attnDate and t3.BatchID=t5.BatchID AND t1.TraineeID = t3.TraineeID
AND t1.attnDate='2016-01-13'
AND(CASE WHEN t5.Slot ='1' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') 
         WHEN t5.Slot ='2' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')
         WHEN t5.Slot ='3' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')
         WHEN t5.Slot ='4' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')
    END)
GROUP BY t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
```

query2:

```
SELECT t1.TraineeID,
       t2.attnDate,
       MIN(t1.attnTime) AS inTime,
              (CASE WHEN MIN(t1.attnTime) < MAX(t1.attnTime) THEN MAX(t1.attnTime) else '' end) AS outTime,
       (CASE WHEN t4.Slot ='1' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'P' 
             WHEN t4.Slot ='2' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='3' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='4' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='1' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'Early Out' 
             WHEN t4.Slot ='2' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='3' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='4' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'Early Out'
             ELSE 'Late-In'
       END) AS Status

FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_assigned t3, tbl_instructor_info t4
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT attnDate FROM tbl_attn_temp) t2
WHERE t1.attndate = t2.attnDate AND t1.TraineeID = t4.InstructorID
AND t1.attnDate='2016-01-13'
AND(CASE WHEN t4.Slot ='1' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') 
         WHEN t4.Slot ='2' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')
         WHEN t4.Slot ='3' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')
         WHEN t4.Slot ='4' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')
    END)
GROUP BY t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
```

Comment: Please create an sqlfiddle.

Comment: Neither query uses `LIMIT` or `UNION`?

Comment: Read about [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). The solution to your problem is explained there.

Answer (score 25):

Just add parenthesis to those union statements. It works for me, for example:
(select ... limit 1)
union
(select ... limit 1)
union 
(select ... limit 1)

union all with parenthesis works too.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by a change on MySQL 5.7. To solve this problem, you have to "nest" your SELECTS, as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM(

    SELECT t1.TraineeID,
           t2.attnDate,
           MIN(t1.attnTime) AS inTime,
           (CASE WHEN MIN(t1.attnTime) < MAX(t1.attnTime) THEN MAX(t1.attnTime) else '' end) AS outTime,
           (CASE WHEN t5.Slot ='1' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'P' 
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='2' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'P'
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='3' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'P'
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='4' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'P'
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='1' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'Early Out' 
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='2' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'Early Out'
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='3' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'Early Out'
                 WHEN t5.Slot ='4' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'Early Out'
                 ELSE 'Late-In'
           END) AS Status

    FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_assigned t3, tbl_batch t5
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT attnDate FROM tbl_attn_temp) t2
    WHERE t1.attndate = t2.attnDate and t3.BatchID=t5.BatchID AND t1.TraineeID = t3.TraineeID
    AND t1.attnDate='2016-01-13'
    AND(CASE WHEN t5.Slot ='1' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') 
             WHEN t5.Slot ='2' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')
             WHEN t5.Slot ='3' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')
             WHEN t5.Slot ='4' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')
        END)
    GROUP BY t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
) AS query1
```

UNION

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT t1.TraineeID,
       t2.attnDate,
       MIN(t1.attnTime) AS inTime,
              (CASE WHEN MIN(t1.attnTime) < MAX(t1.attnTime) THEN MAX(t1.attnTime) else '' end) AS outTime,
       (CASE WHEN t4.Slot ='1' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'P' 
             WHEN t4.Slot ='2' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='3' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='4' AND t1.attnTime<=(SELECT inTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'P'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='1' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1')THEN 'Early Out' 
             WHEN t4.Slot ='2' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='3' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN t4.Slot ='4' AND max(t1.attnTime)<(SELECT outTime FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')THEN 'Early Out'
             ELSE 'Late-In'
       END) AS Status

FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_assigned t3, tbl_instructor_info t4
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT attnDate FROM tbl_attn_temp) t2
WHERE t1.attndate = t2.attnDate AND t1.TraineeID = t4.InstructorID
AND t1.attnDate='2016-01-13'
AND(CASE WHEN t4.Slot ='1' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '1') 
         WHEN t4.Slot ='2' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '2')
         WHEN t4.Slot ='3' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '3')
         WHEN t4.Slot ='4' THEN t1.attnTime BETWEEN(SELECT minLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4') AND (SELECT maxLimit FROM tbl_threshold WHERE id = '4')
    END)
GROUP BY t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
) as query2
```

Answer (score 0):

try keyword `union all` instead of `union`

**try:**

```
select * from (query 1)
union all
(query 2)
```