# How to make a nested query for a specific condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have made this query where I get a list of items by their statuses and get the quantities for each status.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (status) AS Status, COUNT(status) AS Quantity
FROM projects
GROUP BY status
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

And here are the results:

```
Status   Quantity
'PRO', 238
'TER', 75
'SUS', 14
'REI', 3
```

Now for those that have a 'TER' status, I want to get those 'TER' statuses that were updated or modified this year and add them to the results (excluding those 'TER' from previous years). To do this, I have this column `updated_at` (so to speak).

How can I filter those values?

For example, I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (status) AS Status, COUNT(status) AS Quantity,
IF(status='TER',SELECT * FROM projects WHERE year(updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()))
    FROM projects
    GROUP BY status
    ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

But it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the ideas.

**Posible solution**:

I have figured out another solution by using UNION:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT (status) AS Status, COUNT(status) AS Quantity,
    IF(status='TER',SELECT * FROM projects WHERE year(updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()))
        FROM projects
        GROUP BY status
        ORDER BY Quantity DESC)
UNION 
(
SELECT DISTINCT (status) AS Status, COUNT(status) AS Quantity,
    IF(status='TER',SELECT * FROM projects WHERE year(updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()))
        FROM projects
        WHERE year(updated_at) = YEAR(curdate())
        AND status IN ('TER')
        GROUP BY status
        ORDER BY Quantity DESC
)
```

So now I get those projects in 'TER' status and only those within the current year.

So the filter results for 'TER' are now (and should be less results):

```
Status   Quantity
    'PRO', 238
    'SUS', 14
    'REI', 3
    'TER', 45
```

The problem now is that I need to reorder the results, I mean, 'TER' should be in second place... well, I have just found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531301/1883256).

So my final query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT DISTINCT (status) AS Status, COUNT(status) AS Quantity,
        IF(status='TER',SELECT * FROM projects WHERE year(updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()))
            FROM projects
            GROUP BY status
            ORDER BY Quantity DESC)
    UNION 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT (status) AS Status, COUNT(status) AS Quantity,
        IF(status='TER',SELECT * FROM projects WHERE year(updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()))
            FROM projects
            WHERE year(updated_at) = YEAR(curdate())
            AND status IN ('TER')
            GROUP BY status
            ORDER BY Quantity DESC
    )
) a 

GROUP BY status
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

And now I get the results I want and ordered desc:

```
Status   Quantity
    'PRO', 238
    'TER', 45
    'SUS', 14
    'REI', 3
```

Or is there a better way out there?

Comment: IF() needs tree parameters. `IF(condition, result_if_condition_is_true, result_if_condition_is_false)`. So you need to deside, what should be returned if status!='TER' and put it as third parameter.

Comment: so you want to update ALL ROWS where status = TER to current year ?

Comment: There is also a problem with the 2016-02-29. you cant update this date next year

Comment: @BerndBuffen: I don't think OP wants to "update" rows in the table. (If OP said anything about applying changes to rows, I missed it entirely.)

Comment: @BerndBuffen I want to retrieve all different statuses and their quantities ... But only for the 'TER' status, I want to get those of the current year. In this case, if I get all the 'TER', I get 75. If I filter to get only those of the current year, I only get 45. That is what I want to retrieve. Take a look at my question, I have updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the edit to the question, which now better explains the expected result, I've updated this answer with a different query. I still recommend *conditional aggregation*.

```
  SELECT p.status AS Status
       , COUNT( IF( p.status = 'TER'
                  , IF( YEAR(p.updated_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())
                      , 1
                      , NULL
                    ) 
                  , 1
                )
         ) AS Quantity
    FROM projects p
   GROUP BY p.status
   ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

The line breaks and spacing aren't required... I just do that to make it easier to decipher.

For a row that has `status = 'TER'`, it is included in the "count" only if the condition on `updated_at` is satisfied. For all other values of `status`, the row is included in the "count" for that status.

The MySQL-specific expression:

```
                IF( p.status = 'TER'
                  , IF( YEAR(p.updated_at) = YEAR(CURDATE())
                      , 1
                      , NULL
                    ) 
                  , 1
                )
```

Could be replaced with a more ANSI standards compliant expression, for example:

```
                CASE WHEN p.status = 'TER'
                       CASE WHEN YEAR(p.updated_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()
                            THEN 1
                       END
                     ELSE 1
                END
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

What's not clear is what result you want returned.

It looks like you want an additional column returned, and it looks like you might want that to be a "count" of a subset of the rows included in the "Quantity" column.  We can do that.

But first, let's fix some issues with the original query.

The keyword `DISTINCT` is not necessary, it's redundant with the `GROUP BY`. And there's no need for parens around the reference to `status`. That's not illegal to do that, but it doesn't do anything, so it's just confusing. It makes it look as if someone believes that `DISTINCT` is a function. It's not.  It's a keyword that applies to the entire `SELECT` list.

```
  SELECT p.status          AS Status
       , COUNT(p.status)   AS Quantity
    FROM projects p
   GROUP BY p.status
   ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

---

It looks like you want conditional aggregation... if the `updated_at` is a date or datetime in the current year, then include it in the count, otherwise don't.

```
  SELECT p.status          AS Status
       , COUNT(p.status)   AS Quantity
       , SUM(IF(p.status = 'TER' AND YEAR(p.updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()),1,NULL)) AS curcnt
    FROM projects p
   GROUP BY p.status
   ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

---

The expression:

```
IF(p.status = 'TER' AND YEAR(p.updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()),1,NULL)
```

is MySQL shorthand. An equivalent result could be obtained with a more ANSI standards compliant expression:

```
CASE WHEN p.status = 'TER' AND YEAR(p.updated_at)=YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 1 END
```

Depending on how you want a count of "zero" to be displayed on that row, and other rows, you might want to use `0` in place of `NULL`, and/or use an expression that includes additional `IF`, `IFNULL` or `NULLIF` functions.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The desired resultset is not clear from the question.

The answer above is based on the assumption that the desired result is an additional column that contains a "count" of the rows that have `status='TER'` and `updated_at` within the current year.

The answer above demonstrates *conditional aggregation*, and does not make use of a "nested query".

A "nested query" could be used to obtain an equivalent result.

As an example of using a "nested query" as an inline view:

```
  SELECT p.status                AS Status
       , COUNT(p.status)         AS Quantity
       , NULLIF(MAX(q.curcnt),0) AS curcnt
    FROM projects p
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT r.status
                , COUNT(1) AS curcnt
             FROM projects r
            WHERE r.status = 'TER'
              AND YEAR(r.updated_at) = YEAR(NOW())
            GROUP BY r.status
         ) q
      ON q.status = p.status
   GROUP BY p.status
   ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

And as an example of a "nested query" as a subquery in the SELECT list:

```
  SELECT p.status                AS Status
       , COUNT(p.status)         AS Quantity
       , NULLIF( SELECT COUNT(1)
                   FROM projects r
                  WHERE r.status = p.status
                    AND r.status = 'TER'
                    AND YEAR(r.updated_at) = YEAR(NOW())
         ,0) AS curcnt
    FROM projects p
   GROUP BY p.status
   ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

Comment: There is a missing closing bracket after `NULL`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel:  You're right. And that's why we should test, to find syntax problems like that.  (I closed the `IF()` but neglected the closing paren for the `SUM()`.

Comment: Take a look. I actually don't want one more column. I tried using the same query only filtering those 'TER' items for the current year. So I put together the two queries by using `union`. Or is there a better way to achieve this?