# using Union and Order By without getting duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I'm using an `UNION` to merge the results of an exact and a fuzzy search. I want the exact matches to be at the top, and the other results sorted by a column. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531301/3326982) which works fine with `UNION ALL`, but through adding the `rank` column I lose the property of `UNION` (without all) to remove the exact match duplicates from the result set.

Is there an elegant way to solve this, or do I have to manually remove the duplicates?

For reference, my simplified query:

```
SELECT 1 AS [Rank], [CallerID] 
FROM [PHONE]
WHERE [CallerID] = '12345'

UNION

SELECT 2 AS [Rank], [CallerID] 
FROM [PHONE]
WHERE [CallerID] LIKE '12%' AND ABS(LEN([CallerID]) - LEN('12345')) < 3
ORDER BY [Rank] ASC, [CallerID] ASC
```

Result could looke like this:

```
Rank        CallerID
----------- --------------------
1           12345
2           123
2           1233
2           1234
2           12345     <- I don't want this line
2           1236
```

Remark: setting `DISTINCT` for my CallerID won't solve the problem, since my real query has more columns. I really only want to remove duplicates between the two result sets i combine throught the `UNION`.

Comment: `ABS(LEN([CallerID]) - LEN('12345')) < 3` this will not filter `12345`

Comment: @lucumt `LEN('12345')` is 5, so `ABS(5 - 5) < 3` will be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your existing query inside a CTE (here I'm placing your sample data there instead)
and then use a `ROW_NUMBER()` and a further `WHERE` to filter the results:

```
with OriginalQuery as (
select 1 as Rank,  12345 as CallerID union all
select 2 ,123 union all
select 2,1233 union all
select 2,1234 union all
select 2,12345 union all
select 2,1236
), Preferred as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY CallerID /* other columns too? */
        ORDER BY RANK
        ) as rn
    from OriginalQuery
)
select
    *
from
    Preferred
where
    rn = 1
order by Rank,CallerID
```

As indicated, you may have to add more/adjust columns to the `PARTITION` if `CallerID` isn't a key, by itself, for this data.

---

Of course, if there aren't any duplicates in your *underlying data*, and the reason you're getting duplicates is just because you're running two searches and combining the results, it's far simpler to do:

```
SELECT [CallerID] 
FROM [PHONE]
WHERE
    CallerID = '12345' OR
    ([CallerID] LIKE '12%' AND ABS(LEN([CallerID]) - LEN('12345')) < 3)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CallerID='12345' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [CallerID] ASC
```

Where you combine both *searches* rather than combining their results and then use `CASE` to pick out the best matches in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

One variant:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS [Rank], [CallerID] 
    FROM [PHONE]
    WHERE [CallerID] = '12345'
)
SELECT [Rank]
      ,[CallerID]
FROM DataSource

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 AS [Rank], [CallerID] 
FROM [PHONE]
WHERE [CallerID] LIKE '12%' AND ABS(LEN([CallerID]) - LEN('12345')) < 3
    AND [CallerID] NOT IN (SELECT [CallerID] FROM DataSource)
ORDER BY [Rank] ASC, [CallerID] ASC
```