# MySQL LEFT JOIN include original row

Tags: mysql, left-join

How do I left join other table but persist its root row?

## Example

### Table 1

| ID | Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | bar |

### Table 2

| ID | table_id | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Foo bar |
| 2 | 1 | John Doe |

### Expected result

| ID | Column 1 | table_id | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | null | null (This row should persist because this is parent) |
| 1 | foo | 1 | Foo bar |
| 1 | foo | 1 | John Doe |

### Query

```sql
SELECT table1.id, table1.column1, table2.table_id, table2.column2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table_id
```

Comment: UNION will help. PS. You need not in LEFT joining - the output looks like CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Got solve it by,
using UNION ALL and use it on select

Got it here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score -1):

Got solve it by,
using UNION ALL and use it on select

Got it here.
[Using union and order by clause in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531251/using-union-and-order-by-clause-in-mysql)